# Azure App Service Restart required after uploading new contents to FTP

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have some app services and I update the web sites content by uploading the data via FTPS.

Occasionally, after I upload new content, the sites don't display it at all or partially until the app service is restarted.

Is this normal behavior?
What can be done to avoid restarting or monitoring the site and automatically restarting the app service if the site does not appear properly after updating the content?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight, based on your application framework - Unlike Git-based deployments and Zip deployment, FTP deployment doesn't support build automation, such as: dependency restores (such as NuGet, NPM, PIP, and Composer automations), compilation of .NET binaries, generation of web.config (here is a [Node.js example](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps)).

You may generate these necessary files manually on your local machine, and then deploy them together with your app.
Additionally, App Service deploys files to the `wwwroot` folder. It never directly restarts your app.

You may verify if the deployment files are in root folder. A deployment issue is an issue that causes the wrong set of files to get deployed to your site folder (typically d:\home\site\wwwroot).  [Deployment-vs-runtime-issues](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues#deployments-and-web-app-restarts)